# Using spread operator to extend array when using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, spread-syntax

I'm not sure if this is a correct approach, but I'm curious if it can be done. I have an object from which I need to create an array, the key is the item, and the value id the number of times it repeats in the array.

```
const arrayInstructions = {
  'm': 5,
  's': 5,
  'p': 5
}
```

Which should make `['m','m','m','m','m','s','s' ... ]`

This is the working approach:

```
var array = []
Object.keys(arrayInstructions).forEach(function (agenda) {
  array = array.concat( _.fill(Array(arrayInstructions[agenda]), agenda) )
})
```

Can it be done in this manner:

```
var deck = Object.keys(streamDeck).map(function (agenda) {
  var partial = _.fill(Array(streamDeck[agenda]), agenda)
  return ...partial // I know this is wrong
})
```

Comment: No, it can't. You are looking for `concatMap` (which JS doesn't have).

Comment: Consider `Object.keys(obj).reduce((s,k) => s+k.repeat(obj[k]), '').split('')`. It does useless string concatenations, but it's short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use spread on [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to build the final array:

```js
const arrayInstructions = { 'm': 5, 's': 5, 'p': 5 };

// This works because Array.prototype behaves like an empty list here
const deck = Array.prototype.concat(
  ..._.map(arrayInstructions, (times,agenda) => _.times(times, _=>agenda)) 
);

log(JSON.stringify(deck));

function log(x) { document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(x)); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

**UPDATE**

Considering Bergi's recommendation, this version is shorter and does not rely on the behaviour of `Array.prototype` in array context:

```
const deck = [].concat(..._.map(arrayInstructions,
    (times,agenda) => _.times(times, _=>agenda)
));
```

Comment: I would recomment `[].concat(... …)` though

Comment: @Bergi I was considering that as well, somehow `[].concat(...x)` feels more robust. Do you know any concrete scenarios where `Array.prototype.concat(...x)` wouldn't work?

Comment: `Array.prototype[0] = "gotcha"` would be disastrous :-) Admittedly it's a bit contrived, but could happen if someone uses `Array.prototype.push(…)` in a similar manner

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason to use a spread operator here?

In it's simplest form, the spread operator lets you use an array where multiple "elements" or arguments are expected, for your example something like

```
var part = [2, 3];
var arr  = [1, ...part, 4]; // [1,2,3,4]
```

which does seem useful, but you're filling arrays and joining them together, and using `concat` seems more appropriate, however you can limit this to one single call to `concat` if you use `apply` and return a map

```js
"use strict"

const arrayInstructions = {
  'm': 5,
  's': 1,
  'p': 2
}

var deck = [].concat.apply([], Object.keys(arrayInstructions).map(function(k) { 
    return new Array(arrayInstructions[k]).fill(k) 
}));


//output
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(deck, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35705284/1529630#comment59088373_35705284) JS does not have `concatMap`, but you can define this functionality manually:

```
function concatMap(array, func, thisArg) {
  return [].concat.apply([], [].map.call(array, func, thisArg));
}
concatMap(
  Object.keys(arrayInstructions),
  k => new Array(arrayInstructions[k]).fill(k)
);
```